# Windows 7 professional Driver Issues

Tags: windows-7, boot, drivers, issue-tracking

I am using an Intel board made in 2009, model  P5KPLAM-IN series but today I've upgraded it to a DDR4 supported Mother manufactured by ASUS with Intel I3 7th generation and I deployed the same hard disk and I don't have old motherboard for some reason.

Nnow whenever I boot up the old HDD in the new motherboard Windows 7 booting logo starts loading but before fully loaded on screen  Windows 7 reboots automatically.

I tried booting with Windows7 bootable DVD but mouse doesn't works at Windows 7 installation GUI, I also tried loading driver from USB and rescan drivers but nothing happens, Windows don't find drivers in it.

I connected the hard disk to another running pc with Windows7 it shows a single 470GB c: drive .

If somehow I load ASUS motherboard drivers in the attached HDD then I hope everything starts work normal.

Comment: Can you boot in Safe Mode? What support did you get with the new motherboard: a CD with the OEM drivers and applications, or a web link? In either case, copy the OEM files to the old disc, then install them from Safe Mode. If you can identify the old motherboard software, remove it first.

Comment: By default Windows Installer does not run in Safe Mode.

Answer (score 0):

It is a common issue when trying to use an old disk with a new motherboard. The easiest solution would be to use a new disk and mount the old disk as a secondary then copy over what you need.

Alternatively, if there is sufficient room on the disk, use a Linux utility boot CD to repartition the disk, moving the old data to the end of the disk for example then putting a new partition at the start. Then install a fresh copy of Windows. You might need to leave the old data's partition set to hidden until you've set up the new copy of Windows.

Comment: Yes, sir the data is important because It contain server' backup and is there any way to load latest motherboard driver while our window is not booting up because I have latest motherboard driver dvd recive with my new motherboard,

Comment: It isn't easy since the drivers operate at such a low level. It is a job for an expert. By far the easiest, safest and most reliable route is to mount the disk on another computer or, as explained as a secondary disk on the main computer. For future reference, a computer hard disk is not a suitable location for a backup nor should you ever have a single backup copy. By all means use a disk for a *copy* of a backup for speed of access.